# Session storage items cart

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I tried to adapt a code that I found on stackoverflow, but unfortunately I didn't succeed. I want to store a variable that after refresh the page, will remain unchanged, until the cookies are cleared.

In the code I`ll show you, after I pressed refresh, the variable is reset to 0.

Why? Thanks.

JS:

```
 <script>
   var WishCounter = 0;
   let localStorage = window.localStorage
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".accordion-heading").click(function(){
                if($(".accordion-body").is(':visible')){  /* check the condition accordion-body is visible or not */
                    $(".accordion-body").slideUp(200);  /*if content is visible then close accordion-body with specific time duration */
                  $(".plusminus").text('+')    /* add plus sign */
              }
              else{
                  $(this).next(".accordion-body").slideDown(200); /*if content not visible then
                                                                                                              show the accordion-body */
                  $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');  /* add minus sign */
              }
          });
          $(".add-to-cart2").click(function(){
              WishCounter++;
              localStorage.setItem('WishCounter', WishCounter);
              $(".cart-wish").text(WishCounter);
              localStorage.getItem('WishCounter');



          });
      });

      </script>
```

HTML :

```
<a class="add-to-cart2" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
                <img src="images/popit/wish.png" class="buttons-featured-wish" width="91" height="91" border="0" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WishCounter` is always 0 because it gets set on page load. This can be fixed be setting the value of `WishCounter` with `localStorage.getItem();` if it has a value

Example:

```
<script>
    let localStorage = window.localStorage;
    var WishCounter = localStorage.getItem('WishCounter') === null ? 0 : localStorage.getItem('WishCounter');

    $(".cart-wish").text(WishCounter);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".accordion-heading").click(function(){
            if($(".accordion-body").is(':visible')){  /* check the condition accordion-body is visible or not */
                $(".accordion-body").slideUp(200);  /*if content is visible then close accordion-body with specific time duration */
                $(".plusminus").text('+')    /* add plus sign */
            }
            else{
                $(this).next(".accordion-body").slideDown(200); /*if content not visible then
                                                                                                              show the accordion-body */
                $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');  /* add minus sign */
            }
        });
        $(".add-to-cart2").click(function(){
            WishCounter++;
            localStorage.setItem('WishCounter', WishCounter);
            $(".cart-wish").text(WishCounter);

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: 3 issue after i tryed your code: -after refresh the result is the same in my page, 0. -when i trying to triggered the button again, counter starting from 3, i don`t know why. -when i refresh the page and trying to push the button again, the counter starting from the last session (ex. before refresh my count was 3. after refresh and press button, it`s not 1, it`s 4)

Comment: I updated the code, could you check it again? @Alexandru